# Cannot Delete and getting 404 not found error in router.delete

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, vuex

In my application, i am passing the request param id in router.delete and communicating that with vuex service. While triggering action api is fired but getting 404 not found and there is not request payload as well.

**Express route.delete**

```
    router.delete('/favorites/:favoriteId', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(Number(req.params.favoriteId));
  });
```

**Vuex service**

```
 /**
 *
 * @param {*} favouriteId number
 */

export async function deleteUserFavourites(favouriteId) {
    const response = await http.delete('favorites',favouriteId);
    return response;
}
```

**vuex actions**

```
async removeFavorites({ commit }, payload) {
    const favourites = await service.deleteUserFavourites({
        id: payload.favouriteId
    });
    commit('removeFavorites', favourites);
},
```

[image]

**component action trigger**

```
async handleListClick(item) {
            console.log(item.id);
            await this.removeFavorites({
                id: item.id
            });
        }
    }
```

**It is showing in api response**

**server.js**

```
    const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Express Server Setup
const server = express();
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(express.static('public'));

// Webpack HMR
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.local');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(
    compiler,
    webpackConfig.devServer
);
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler);
server.use(webpackDevMiddleware);
server.use(webpackHotMiddleware);

// Server Startup
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('*****************************************');
    console.log('*****************************************');
    console.log('** Server is listening at PORT 3000. ****');
    console.log('** http://localhost:3000/      ****');
    console.log('*****************************************');
    console.log('*****************************************');
});

// Mock APIs
const router = require('express').Router();
const routesPath = path.join(__dirname, './routes');
const filenames = fs.readdirSync(routesPath);
filenames.forEach(file => {
    if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
        console.log(`route ${file} loaded`);
        router.use('/', require(path.join(routesPath, file)));
    }
});
server.use('/api', router);

// Vue entrypoint
const template = require('./template');
server.get('/**', (req, res) => {
    const page = template();
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html').send(page);
});
```

Comment: Can you also show the Header tab screenshot? Specifically the requested URL?

Comment: Id is not passing through.. Is it not understanding the request parameter??

Comment: `consloe.log(favouriteId)` right above `const response = await http.delete('favorites',favouriteId);` and see what you get. If the id is not there, start working you way up and try to pinpoint where the problem originates.

Comment: till service and actions are communicating properly. I am getting the favouriteId properly. The problem is route.delete is not setting up the route properly. requested url : localhost:3000/api/favorites

Comment: Assuming `/api` is a proxy to a backend server, the server needs to have a route for `DELETE /api/favorites`. Have you confirmed that?

Comment: yes `/api` is a proxy to a backend server. But, post( /api/favorites) and get(/api/favorites) is working fine. only delete is not working

Comment: Sounds like you have not setup a `DELETE` route in your backend.

Comment: i have added server.js entrypoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your api endpoint is this: `'/favorites/:favoriteId'`, You have to app favoriteId at the end of the request url not in the body.
so your request have to be like this:

```
export async function deleteUserFavourites(favouriteId) {
const response = await http.delete('favorites/' + favoriteId.toString());
return response;
```

}